# How to automate running multiple nodejs apps through console with different config files?

Tags: node.js, system-design

I have a node app that I need to run PER user account. The contents of the app will all be the same besides the config file that the user will edit.

So, the user would be able to freely edit their config file and submit it to my server. Then, I would need a listener to be able to realize that a config file has been submitted. Finally, the server would have to create a new copy of the app and inject the config file and run "node app.js" in a new console.

I'm completely lost and no idea where to even start looking for information.